# Calcular Edad apartir de fecha de nacimiento oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo este Dato ya guardado en una tabla que se llama empleado, quisiera saber como le puedo calcular edad teniendo la fecha de nacimiento.

```
    INSERT INTO Empleado 
    (identificacion, Nombre, Apellido,AniosExperiencia, Salario, FechaNacimiento,
    Cargo)
    VALUES (01, 'Juan', 'Velez', 2, 1300000,TO_DATE('1990/01/07','YYYY/MM/DD'),
   'Pintor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta algo así, yo lo probe y solamente tuve un dia de error entre fechas:

```
SELECT FLOOR((TRUNC(SYSDATE)-TRUNC(FechaNacimiento))/365) FROM Empleado
```